# The Power Supply can influence in performance?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, power-supply

I bought a new computer, I have a core i5 4690, 16gb ram hyper-x, 120 gb SSD + 500Gb HDD and a Radeon R7 360 2gb, the only thing that is not new in my computer is the power supply, a 500W "Wise Case" bought in 2009. I played many games without problem, almost all settings in High or Ultra, games like GTA5, Fallout4, FIFA16, BF3, CS:GO. Etc.
But, in some games I have a weird problem, like League of Legends. Sometimes the video stops for almost 2 seconds, most of time is when someone use some magic skill near me or something else. I was thinking in change the my GPU, because I tried take off the GPU and play using the built-in Intel HD Graphics, and I do not have any lag, with the HIGHEST video settings. But today I remembered my old power supply, there is a possibility of power supply is breaking the performance? Maybe it is not giving the needed power to GPU or something else. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This could be a heat issue. Either the GPU itself is overheating or heat from the GPU is a factor in causing the CPU or RAM to overheat.

Comment: I can say without a shadow of doubt, this problem ,is not caused by the PSU.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but if the heat is the problem why the lag happen randomly? I think if it was a heat issue the lag will be constant, getting worst each minute, and this is not what is happening. No?

Comment: @Ramhound if this problem was happening to you, what do you do? Change GPU?

Comment: @rochasdv Typically CPU and GPU overheat detection works well and produces that kind of behavior because it's expected that they might trigger under ordinary conditions. But the overheat detection in other components such as motherboard chipsets and RAM do not always respond as predictably and smoothly as you might want because they're not expected to trigger. Some water cooled systems have worse airflow around the CPU and motherboard chipset because they don't have that big fan on the CPU heatsink creating airflow in that area.